# por que o FloatingActionButton está transparente?

Tags: java, android, material-design

Estou com um problema depois que atualizei a lib support.design:22.2.0 para 23.0.1, o `floatingActionButton` passou a ser transparente quando executado na API 10.

Aqui está o código:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnClick"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorFAB"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom" />
```

[image]

Comment: Você está no Stack Overflow em Português. As perguntas por aqui são em Português! Edite e traduz ai, Fabiano. Aproveito para recomendar a leitura do [tour].

Comment: valeu pela dica!

Comment: Poderia incluir o valor do `@color/colorFab`? Acredito que esteja colocando um valor no formato `rrggbbaa` mas o certo é `aarrggbb`, vide [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Color).

Comment: já tirei, coloquei denovo, coloquei app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary", android:background="@color/colorPrimary", criei um xml no drawable e coloquei como background, mas nada muda. Mas na preview do android studio funciona legal e em algumas APIs,como android 4.1, porem quando executado na API 10, android 2.3.6, fica assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que isso é um bug do Android 10 que foi corrigido na versão 14, de uma olhada na [issue #183315](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183315) mas que apareceu durante a versão 23.0.0 da design library.

Existem duas soluções, uma simples e outra que depende de uma sobreescrever o comportamento do `FAB`.

#### 1) Voltar para a versão 22.2.1.

As vezes isso é comum (infelizmente). Se existe um bug da biblioteca, e que não tem solução, basta regredir se não usar nenhuma função específica da versão.

#### 2) Criar uma classe que herda do `FloatActionButton` da design library como um "workaround", sugerido pelo comentário [#9](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183315#c9):

```
public class TintFloatingActionButton extends FloatingActionButton implements TintableBackgroundView {

    static final int[] PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_pressed,
            android.R.attr.state_enabled};
    static final int[] FOCUSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET = {android.R.attr.state_focused,
            android.R.attr.state_enabled};

    private static final int[] TINT_ATTRS = {
            android.R.attr.background
    };

    private TintInfo mBackgroundTint;

    public TintFloatingActionButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TintFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TintFloatingActionButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if (TintManager.SHOULD_BE_USED) {
            TintTypedArray a = TintTypedArray.obtainStyledAttributes(getContext(), attrs,
                    TINT_ATTRS, defStyleAttr, 0);

            if (a.hasValue(0)) {
                setSupportBackgroundTintList(createColorStateList(a.getResourceId(0, -1)));
            }

            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private static ColorStateList createColorStateList(int selectedColor) {
        final int[][] states = new int[3][];
        final int[] colors = new int[3];
        int i = 0;

        states[i] = FOCUSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = selectedColor;
        i++;

        states[i] = PRESSED_ENABLED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = selectedColor;
        i++;

        // Default enabled state
        states[i] = new int[0];
        colors[i] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
        i++;

        return new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSupportBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList tint) {
        if (mBackgroundTint == null) {
            mBackgroundTint = new TintInfo();
        }
        mBackgroundTint.mTintList = tint;
        mBackgroundTint.mHasTintList = tint != null;
        applySupportBackgroundTint();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public ColorStateList getSupportBackgroundTintList() {
        return mBackgroundTint != null ? mBackgroundTint.mTintList : null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSupportBackgroundTintMode(@Nullable PorterDuff.Mode tintMode) {
        if (mBackgroundTint == null) {
            mBackgroundTint = new TintInfo();
        }
        mBackgroundTint.mTintMode = tintMode;
        mBackgroundTint.mHasTintMode = tintMode != null;
        applySupportBackgroundTint();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public PorterDuff.Mode getSupportBackgroundTintMode() {
        return mBackgroundTint != null ? mBackgroundTint.mTintMode : null;
    }

    private void applySupportBackgroundTint() {
        if (getBackground() != null && mBackgroundTint != null) {
            TintManager.tintViewBackground(this, mBackgroundTint);
        }
    }
}
```

Código completo neste gist: https://gist.github.com/arturgaleno/5cca1934ed324bd2d9a7

Comment: funcionou. mas depois de clicado fica transparente novamente.